# Create a Customized Menu in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-menu

I'm needing help creating a customizable menu for my Android app. Is it possible to create a RecyclerView for the menu, create a layout for the cell, and do a for loop for the menu item name and image? Or do I need to create an actual navigation menu in my layout directory? Thank you!

**iOS Preview**

[image]

**Android Preview**

[image]

Comment: Yes, what you want to do is possible. I am not sure if there is a more technical answer you are seeking here.

Comment: I'm just wondering if I can use a RecyclerView in this case?